# NumberTheory: Proof or disproof the following. Dividing and adding

Tags: number-theory

> Proof or disproof the following. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number. If we divide the digits of $N$ with preserving the order and adding them together we will get a digit ( a number less than 10) in at most 3 steps.

In other word if we have the number $9834530023$ we can parting it into $9+ 8 + 3+4 + 53 +0 +0 + 2 +3 = 82 $ then $8 + 2 = 10$. Hence $1 + 0 = 1$. In 3 steps

Lets take another example $N = 111\cdots 1111$ alot of $1's$. Suppose we have $k$ $1's$ then $k = 9t + r$ such that $r< 9$. So we can divide $N$ into nine number each with $t$ digits. Hence

$9 (  \underset{t-times}{\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}} ) + \underset{r-times}{\underbrace{1 + \cdots +1}} = \underset{t-times}{\underbrace{9+\cdots + 9}} + 1 +r-1 = 10^{t+1} + r-1 $
But the last number is like $1000\cdots 00s$ which is $1+ s <10$. 
how i can prove it for general?

Comment: Just to clarify:  you are saying "it is possible to find groupings of the sort described which have the given property", yes?  You aren't suggesting that every such grouping will have the desired property.

Comment: yes you can reach a digit in at most 3 steps dividing and adding

Comment: Here is a better example $900183439123$ we do consider it like $9 + 0 + 0 + 18 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 9 +1 + 23 = 70$ now we have $70$ and $7+0 = 7 <10$ in two steps. We are claiming we can do that for any number in less than 3 steps.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Do you know the answer (yes/no) even if you don't know a proof?

Comment: I see this in a group of math in facebook someone asked it. I think it is true. I forgot to mention something the asker said this is true for any number in any base also.@user2566092

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For any number $N$, you can come up with a much larger number (say, basically all 2's, with $N/2$ digits) such that when you split the digits and add them, you get $N$. You can repeat this construction as many times as you want.

Comment: Still unclear. Suppose we have $ N=998352345679234$ we can think about a number $r$ which is $22\cdots2$ when we add them we get our number but I can move from $r$ to $N$ but i cannot move in the other direction!

Comment: @AmerYR Basically what I'm saying is now treat $r$ as your new $N$ and then think of a new $r$, and keep repeating this process.

Comment: @user2566092   I believe (possibly incorrectly) that the confusion here comes from the fact that OP is only asking that there exist some grouping that works.  Sure, the path you chose (through N) won't work, but you have to prove that there isn't some other path which does work.

Comment: @lulu Yeah the example at the beginning of the post didn't make that clear but I thought there was a slight chance something like that might be going on (I should have asked), which is why I supposed the digit 2 instead of the digit 1. I'll try to come up with a better construction.

Comment: It is easy for some cases like if we have a number with repeated digit. And if we have a number with million digits the sum of the digits is less than or equal to $9\cdot 10^6$ again the sum of the digits is less than or equal to $60$ and the sum of the digits is less than $14$. in the last case i did not reach a digit but a number with two digits.

Comment: @AmerYR  It's interesting.  I expect it is true because there are so many ways to group, seems like there should be enough options.  But I can't seem to get a handle on it.